# How to hightlight the max ( or min) number in each row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Say I have data from A1 to E10. So it's 10 x 5 cells. I know how to do each row individually, using conditional formatting. Say for row 1:

Select A1, conditional formatting -> `=max($A$1:$E$1)`, then "brush" through the whole row.

[image: Q28058175 example]

But if I have a large table, this is not very efficient.

How do I efficiently ask Excel to highlight the maximum (alternatively, minimum) number in each row(column)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please select the range, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, **Format values where this formula is true:**

```
=A1=MAX($A1:$E1)
```

<kbd>Format</kbd>, select formatting of choice, OK, OK.